# how to extend the following excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to generate month ending wise data for a given start and end period; number of months is varying for different applicants.

The following data is to be generated by user input and may vary in number per applicant:

> Column ‘A’ -- month ending date
>
> Column ‘B’ -- EMI
>
> Column 'C' -- interest portion
>
> Column ‘D’ -- principle portion
>
> > and so on.

I also want to calculate sum of each column at end and the row changing the size of sheet based on column “A” no of rows. Please help.

```
Sub GenerateDates()
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim currentDate As Date

    startDate = Range("b4").Value
    endDate = Range("b8").Value

    currentDate = startDate
    Range("a17").Select

    Do Until currentDate = endDate

        ActiveCell.Value = currentDate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        'currentDate = DateAdd("m", 1, currentDate)
        currentDate = DateSerial(Year(currentDate), Month(currentDate) + 2, 0)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems Pivot Table will do the trick considering your requirement. Convert your data into an Excel Table, insert a pivot table, drag the Date column in Row Area and group the dates by Month and drag the columns into the Value area which need to be summarized.

Comment: there is no data, data will be generated once few fields were filled, once the data is generated for one applicant i have to calculate summation of each column and past in another sheet then i have to calculate another applicant and so on..

Comment: @anil, your problem here seems to be knowing the last row in column A? and using that last column to sum other columns B, C, D ... ?

Comment: @anil So what? You can create a Pivot Table based on an empty Excel Table also. You start filling the table and refresh the Pivot Table, that's all you need if Pivot Table works for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following edit based on what I can understand on what you want to do:

```
Sub GenerateDates()

    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'or whatever name of sheet you have
    Set wbDesti = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\DestinationFile.xlsx") ' <<< path to source workbook
    Set sh = wbDesti.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Sheet in destination file

    'automatically find the last row in Sheet A.
    iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row + 1

    startDate = ws.cells(1,1).Value
    endDate = ws.cells(2,1).Value

    currentDate = startDate
    'Range("a17").Select 'removed this to avoid .Select functions

    dim row as integer 'declare another variable for row...

    'row = iRow

    'Do Until currentDate = endDate

        'ws.cells(row,1).value = currentDate
        'row = row + 1

        'currentDate = DateAdd("m", 1, currentDate)
        'currentDate = DateSerial(Year(currentDate), Month(currentDate) + 2, 0)

    'Loop
    Dim col as integer
    col = 2 'start with B
    Do until col = 4
        sh.cells(1,col) = application.worksheetfunction.sum(ws.range("B"&10&":"&"B"&":"&60))
        '***other codes goes here to transfer data same as above.
        col = col + 1
    Loop

    wbDesti.quit
    Set sh = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: my data is like this... cell A1 EMI starting date, A2 EMI ending date and A3  is no.of EMIs say 50 months,  B column, C & D columns having data values which are changing automatically by changing above three cell values, data in B,C,D columns starting from row number 10 i.e B10:B60, C10:C60 etc. Column A10:A60 month end date generated by using above code and the A1,A2,A3 values will change for every applicant. Now, i want get sum in each column of B.C & D at end of data,when ever change the A1,A2,A3, please help

Comment: may i know what is "EMI"? I guess you just have to change the range of the sum function above. I put it as vertical (B1:B10).

Comment: Can you try the edited code now and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: EMI is equated monthly instalment of a loan

Comment: sh.cells(1,1) = application.worksheetfunction.sum(ws.range("B"&1&":"&"B"&":"&iRow).value)

Comment: above code is error

Comment: Aplicant 1    
loan Start date 3/31/2017   
Loan end date 12/31/2017   
No of EMIs 10   
Loan Amount 500000   
ROI 9%   
Date of EMI EMI Principal Interest Balance
31-Mar-17 52086 48336 3750 451664
30-Apr-17 52086 48699 3388 402966
31-May-17 52086 49064 3023 353902
30-Jun-17 52086 49432 2655 304471
31-Jul-17  52086 49803 2284 254669
31-Aug-17 52086 50176 1911 204493
30-Sep-17 52086 50552 1534 153941
31-Oct-17 52086 50932 1155 103010
30-Nov-17 52086 51314 773 51697
31-Dec-17 52086 51697 389 0
         Sum 520860 500005 20862

Comment: @anil, did you change the destination directory into a valid one? Edit: Sorry, my bad, above code `ws.range(...).value `should be ws.range(...)` only.

Answer (score 1):

@Anil try this:

```
Sub GenerateDates()
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim cnt As Integer

    startDate = Range("b2").Value
    endDate = Range("b3").Value

    currentDate = startDate
    Range("a9").Select

    cnt = ActiveSheet.Range("E3")
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A10"), ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).ClearContents

    With ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A9"), ActiveSheet.Range("A9").End(xlToRight))
        .Copy
        .Offset(1).Resize(cnt - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    For i = 1 To Range("A8").End(xlToRight).Column - Range("A8").Column
        Range("A8").Offset(cnt + 1, i) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A8").Offset(1, i).Resize(cnt))
    Next
End Sub
```

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B806lR28X1buNTJZYlRtdUF5bWs/view?usp=sharing)  to download the solution.

In the excel, there are 5 columns: End of month Date, EMI, Interest, Principal, Amount Outstanding. You have to 4 input fields: Start Period, End Period, Amount, Interest. The Calculate button runs the above macro. The first row, i.e. the 9th row has the formulas and are copy and pasted for the number of periods to get the dates and calculations. At the end, the summation of columns is taken. I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: How to extend this to calculate sum for more than one column say "C","D", and "E"

Comment: Sub anil111()
Dim N As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(N + 1, "c").Formula = "=SUM(c1:c" & N & ")"
End Sub

Comment: not working it is deleting entire data